# Parameters of resource_filename in pkg_resource in python

Tags: python, pkg-resources

I don't understand how exactly pkg_resource.resource_filename() work and what are its parameters. I searched a lot on web but their official documentation does not cover it well. Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few examples. I have wheel 0.24 installed in an old environment:

```
pkg_resources.resource_filename('spamalot', "wheel/__init__.py")    
ImportError: No module named spamalot
```

The first argument has to be importable. The second argument should be a relative, /-separated path, including on systems that use \ to separate paths.

```
In [27]: pkg_resources.resource_filename('distutils', "wheel/__init__.py")
Out[27]: '/opt/pyenv/lib64/python2.7/distutils/wheel/__init__.py'
```

If it is importable, you will get a path inside the imported name. In this case it doesn't matter whether the file exists.

```
In [28]: pkg_resources.resource_filename(pkg_resources.Requirement.parse('wheel>0.23.0'), "core.py")
Out[28]: '/opt/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/core.py'
```

You can pass a requirement, and it will check if you actually have it installed. Now the path is relative to the install directory and not the `wheel` package.

```
In [29]: pkg_resources.resource_filename(pkg_resources.Requirement.parse('wheel>0.27.0'), "core.py")

VersionConflict: (wheel 0.24.0 (/opt/pyenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('wheel>0.27.0'))
```

If the requirement is not installed it will complain.

One reason the `Requirement` feature exists is because it's possible to have eggs for multiple versions of the same package on the path, and `pkg_resources` will add the requested version, but this feature is not used very much any more.

These examples are pretty simple, but `resource_filename` will also work if your resources are inside a `.zip` file or any other supported import location (it is possible to hook Python's import system so that imports come from anywhere - sqlite databases, the network, ..., and resource_filename should be able to work with these if the right hooks are installed.)

Comment: Okay Thanks for answering. I am getting how pkg_resources work but what location is resource_filename() returning? Is it the location of install module in first arguement or is it the location of the file or directory in second arguement?

Comment: The second command returns /home/ayush/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/distutils/wheel/__init__.py to me. What does it specifies?

Comment: resource_filename(a, b) is returning you a path underneath where the module a is installed. In the simple case it just joins the path of a with b. In complex cases (like a zip file) it extracts the resource to the filesystem first and returns that path.

Comment: Ohh okay I got it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Official documentation is [available here](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PkgResources) (as documented in the [relevant PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0365/#implementation-and-documentation)).

> **resource_filename(package_or_requirement, resource_name)**
>
> Sometimes, it is not sufficient to access a resource in string or stream form, and a true filesystem filename is needed. In such cases,
> you can use this method (or module-level function) to obtain a
> filename for a resource. If the resource is in an archive distribution
> (such as a zipped egg), it will be extracted to a cache directory, and
> the filename within the cache will be returned. If the named resource
> is a directory, then all resources within that directory (including
> subdirectories) are also extracted. If the named resource is a C
> extension or "eager resource" (see the setuptools documentation for
> details), then all C extensions and eager resources are extracted at
> the same time.
>
> Archived resources are extracted to a cache location that can be managed by the following two methods: